# How to pass a dictionary and a context in the same return render() function from a view to template in python

Tags: python, django

I would like to list a data from database and one variable in the context, however, when i pass both in the same return render() function it gives me 
This is my view
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr1Vd.png)

The dictionary i want to use it to list like this -> [Dictionary list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFnZX.png)

and my context am using it to switch menus and it looks like this ~> [context's use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HycZQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply update the context and pass the context only, replace statement:

```
return render(request, 'dashboards/dash.html', {'List_dash': Lista_dash}, context)
```

with

```
context.update({'Lista_dash': Lista_dash})
return render(request, 'dashboards/dash.html', context)
```

where `Lista_dash = CLDashboards.objects.all()`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. If i have some more can i do the same for other two or four?

Comment: Yes, you can. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I see no reasons why you can't just simply add DB data to context:

```
...
context = {'modulo': 1, 'List_dash': Lista_dash}
return render(request, 'dashboards/dash.html', context)
```

Comment: because i use them for different purpose.  Because i use "List_dash" to list the records in the database and context as variable to switch between panels.